# How is CSRF checked in Django

Tags: python, django

Django has a CSRF module to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery. To use that we have to import the csrf module from django, and pass the request, and pass it along to the template.
Like this.

```
def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("login.html",c)
```

At the template end, we just need to addit to the form like this

```
<form action="/articles/create/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{ form.as_ul }}
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Article" />
</form>
```

But at the receiving end(/articles/create/ )- here , we do not check for the token. Is this CSRF token checked automatically by django or do we need to do anything? because we are also able to create a form without this token and that would work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Django handles it for you, you just only need to pass it to the template and pass it to the view using `{% csrf_token %}` . In fact you dont need to pass the token explicitly, using render shortcut, Django will pass the token for you.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
...
  return render(request, 'my_template.html', my_data)
```

Comment: So if any other website tries to post the data, it raises an error. But what if i make a form without the csrf token.

Comment: Then if you are using CSRF it will fail, there is a csrf exempt decorator you can use to avoid CSRF checking...but that is not a recommended method.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt

Comment: You cant create a form without csrf token, because csrf token is not "inside" a form that you create. It is inside the request call object. If you want to disable csrf token protection, you need use do this: import django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt  and add @csrf_exempt on the top of your view. It will disable csrf token protection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to enable the Middleware in your settings:

```
django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware
```

Then in your form template, after the opening tag, use:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

In your view:

If you are using generic views then you are covered, since generic views make use of the RequestContext (which in turn uses the csrf context processor).
Class Based Views also don't need this, the only time you will need to deal with CSRF inside the view is if you are not using any of the above:

```
django.core.context_processors.csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("login.html",c)
```

Additionally if you are using AJAX you need to implement some extra work in order to transmit the CSRF to the CSRF enabled views.
You can learn more:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/